# Calling a Web Service (WCF) method in C#

Tags: web-services, wcf

Ho would I call a Web Service (WCF) method in c# please?

I've got a Web Service and now I would like to consume it in a another Web Service method.

Comment: If you have the `.wsdl` with you , simply generate a client proxy using SvcUtil.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it as a client. For this you have to add a service reference in the other service and then contact the previous one.

Run first service -> go to second service -> right click on references -> add service reference -> type the link to the first webservice and search then add it.

After your service has connected you can call the other one.

```
WCF.wcfServiceClient client = new WCF.wcfServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IwcfService");
            client.Method();
```